# Cannot connect to MS SQL SERVER

Tags: java, sql, servlets

I have JBoss and MSSQL Server 2008.  `Sqljdbc.jar` is in Java Resources/Libraries, but I still have a `ClassNotFoundExeption`.

This is my servlet :

```
package work.Model;

import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.sql.*;

public class SQLServlet extends HttpServlet {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

public SQLServlet() {
    super();
}

final String server = "localhost";
final int port = 1433;
final String user = "work"; 
final String password = "workdb";
final String database = "workDB";
final String jdbcUrl = "jdbc:sqlserver://"+server+":"+1433+";user="+user+";password="+password+";databaseName="+database+"";



protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {



    try {
        System.out.println("try to load driver");
        Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
        System.out.println("# - Driver Loaded");

        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(jdbcUrl);
        System.out.println("# - Connection Obtained");

        Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
        System.out.println("# - Statement Created");

        String loginCheck = "SELECT userID,username,password FROM USERS where username=? and password=?";



    } catch (Exception ex) {

        System.out.println("Error : "+ex);
    }

}
```

}

The error is  :

```
[STDOUT] Error : java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver from BaseClassLoader@724c0116{VFSClassLoaderPolicy@5bdb85f9{name=vfszip:/D:/Jboss/jboss-5.1.0.GA/server/default/deploy/Work.war/
```

How to correctly connect to MSSQL Server?

Comment: You should try not to hardcode DB driver class, user, password, urls. That means that making any change to your DB will force you to recompile your webapp (with the risk of forgetting to update some servlets), and cause lots of issues. If you do not want to make use of the tools J2EE (including JBoss) offers to do that (google "JBoss datasource") at the very least you could load them from a Properties file.

Answer (score 1):

Try putting the `SqlJdbc.jar` in `D:/Jboss/jboss-5.1.0.GA/server/default/lib` folder and restart the server.

Answer (score 1):

Servlets are used in the web application that has a predefined folder structure. As soon as you are not creating a deployment structure for JBoss server you have a chance to put JDBC driver jar to the `WEB-INF/lib` folder or copy it there during build.

Another approach is create a JBoss service that publish a datasource on JNDI and use its context and retrieve them on RAR deployment.